# SQL get multiply child element

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table represents n levels of parent-child relationship.

```
   ParentID  ChildID
1   A        B
2   B        C
3   B        D
3   C        E
......
```

If I have Parent ID A, how do I have all A, B, C, D, E in a SQL statement (assuming every element can have children/s, so there may be some recursion needed).

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: what Database are you using ? Please be specific

Comment: I want to select all the IDs related to A (A, B, C, D, E in this case). I am using MS SQL server. Thanks!

Comment: how does the expected result looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is a recursive common table expression (CTE). It is good to extract a hierarchy.

This link should help: [MSDN Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)
And I've copied the main example below.

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
WITH DirectReports (ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID, 
        0 AS Level
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
    SELECT e.ManagerID, e.EmployeeID, e.Title, edh.DepartmentID,
        Level + 1
    FROM dbo.MyEmployees AS e
    INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory AS edh
        ON e.EmployeeID = edh.BusinessEntityID AND edh.EndDate IS NULL
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d
        ON e.ManagerID = d.EmployeeID
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT ManagerID, EmployeeID, Title, DeptID, Level
FROM DirectReports
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department AS dp
    ON DirectReports.DeptID = dp.DepartmentID
WHERE dp.GroupName = N'Sales and Marketing' OR Level = 0;
GO
```